# How to remove line break in lines with 10 columns separated by comma delimiter

Tags: shell, awk, sh, newline

I need to remove line break in each line with 10 columns separated by comma delimiter.
This is the input:

```
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA,N/A,Input,1,1,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,11131,Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow
... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6711630149',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA,N/A,Input,1,2,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,11131,Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow
... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6342311300',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
PREST_TELEFONE_HIS,N/A,Input,1,3,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,8361,Error loading row to target table [PREST_TELEFONE_HIS]. Error message [
FnName: Execute -- [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column ""*N"" is not allowed.  SQLSTATE=23502
],2,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
```

This should be the output:

```
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA,N/A,Input,1,1,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,11131,Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6711630149',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA,N/A,Input,1,2,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,11131,Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6342311300',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
PREST_TELEFONE_HIS,N/A,Input,1,3,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,8361,Error loading row to target table [PREST_TELEFONE_HIS]. Error message [FnName: Execute -- [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column ""*N"" is not allowed.  SQLSTATE=23502],2,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
```

So far, I've tried this awk command:

```
awk -F"," 'NF=10{printf("%s",$0);getline;print;next}1'
```

Output:

```
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA N/A Input 1 1 1 04/30/2020 19:52:20 1588287140 11131 Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6711630149',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA N/A Input 1 2 1 04/30/2020 19:52:20 1588287140 11131 Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6342311300',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
PREST_TELEFONE_HIS N/A Input 1 3 1 04/30/2020 19:52:20 1588287140 8361 Error loading row to target table [PREST_TELEFONE_HIS]. Error message [FnName: Execute -- [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column *N is not allowed.  SQLSTATE=23502
] 2 N/A N/A N/A -1 -1 N/A  ] 2 N/A N/A N/A -1 -1 N/A
```

I don't know why the command is removing the comma delimiter from the lines. I know the 6th line does not have 10 columns thats why is not removing the break line...
Any tips?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to **test** if `NF` is equal to `10`, in which case you should use `NF==10`; `NF=10` says to redefine `NF` as `10` which in turn causes the input to be copied/rewritten ... using the comma (,) as input delimiter and space as the (default) output delimiter; if I cut the input string down some and set the output delimiter to a period you can get an  idea of what's going on: `awk -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS="."} NF=10{printf(".%s.",$0)}' <<< 'a,b,c,d,e'` ==> `a.b.c.d.e......`

Comment: will your 3rd field always have value as `Input` ?

Comment: @markp-fuso I'm almost there however I think it is not the best way to do that: `awk -F"," 'NF==10{printf("%s",$0);getline;print;next}1' | awk 'NF>10{print}{}' | cut -d',' -f1-10` Thanks

Comment: @DigvijayS yes it will. Also the 2rd field will always have value `N/A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
awk -F","  '{OFS=",";  if ($3 != "Input") {printf "%s", $0} else {printf "\n%s" ,$0}}' |sed '1d'  | sed  -e '$a\'
```

Demo :

```
$cat file.txt 
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA,N/A,Input,1,1,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,11131,Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow
... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6711630149',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA,N/A,Input,1,2,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,11131,Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow
... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6342311300',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
PREST_TELEFONE_HIS,N/A,Input,1,3,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,8361,Error loading row to target table [PREST_TELEFONE_HIS]. Error message [
FnName: Execute -- [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column ""*N"" is not allowed.  SQLSTATE=23502
],2,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
$awk -F","  '{OFS=",";  if ($3 != "Input") {printf "%s", $0} else {printf "\n%s" ,$0}}' file.txt  | sed '1d'  | sed  -e '$a\'
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA,N/A,Input,1,1,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,11131,Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6711630149',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA,N/A,Input,1,2,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,11131,Transformation [EXP_TRANSF_DE_PARA] had an error evaluating variable column [v_NUFONE]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_INTEGER]: decimal operation overflow... i:TO_INTEGER(u:RTRIM(u:LTRIM(u:'6342311300',u:' ���'),u:' ���'),i:0)].,3,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
PREST_TELEFONE_HIS,N/A,Input,1,3,1,04/30/2020 19:52:20,1588287140,8361,Error loading row to target table [PREST_TELEFONE_HIS]. Error message [FnName: Execute -- [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column ""*N"" is not allowed.  SQLSTATE=23502],2,N/A,N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
$
```

Explnation:

`awk -F","` < -- Set delimiter as `,`

`'{OFS=",";` < --  Set output field seprator as `,` because we will be using `printf` for  formating text

`if ($3 != "Input") {printf "%s", $0}` <-- If 3rd column  of current record is not `"Input"` print current record. Please note we are not adding `newline` so record won't be terminated.

`else {printf "\n%s" ,$0}}'` <-- If current record have is record we want add a line break `\n` before printing the record.

`sed '1d'` < -- delete first record. This will be empty line as our record have "Input"

`sed  -e '$a\'` <-- add a new line at the end of the file.

Comment: This solution only handles newlines in the third field, right?

Comment: No. It checks if the record needs to be collapsed or not based on the value in the 3rd field.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Bash script which solves your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

fieldCount=20

#filter out newlines which are not record separators
fieldNum=1
while read -N1 -r ch; do
    if [ "$ch" = "," ]; then
        fieldNum="$((fieldNum + 1))"
    elif [ "$ch" = $'\n' ] && [ "$fieldNum" = "$fieldCount" ]; then
        fieldNum=1
    fi
    if [ "$ch" != $'\n' ] || [ "$fieldNum" = 1 ]; then
        printf "$ch"
    fi
done
printf '\n'
```

The option -N1 reads one character at a time (instead of one line at a time) and the option -r treats backslash as an ordinary character.

The problem can also be solved with a simple C program of comparable size:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int fieldCount = 20;
    int fieldNum, ch;

    /*filter out newlines which are not record separators*/
    fieldNum = 1;
    ch = getchar();
    while (ch != EOF) {
        if (ch == ',') {
            fieldNum++;
        } else if ((ch == '\n') && (fieldNum == fieldCount)) {
            fieldNum = 1;
        }
        if ((ch != '\n') || (fieldNum == 1)) {
            putchar(ch);
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that I only can use shell script to achieve that. Thanks anyway

Comment: @RobertAlmeida I have added a Bash solution now.

Comment: August Karlstrom although your solution and markp-fuso's solution are effective markp-fuso's solution seems more efficient for me. Best regards

Comment: @RobertAlmeida This solution handles newlines in any field though.